# Failure: User pages profile page should have title "Example User"

Tags: rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's rails tutorial and I am in the middle of chapter 7, trying to configure the user profile. I am using devise, omitted creating a `views/users/new.html.erb` page by instead leaving it to devise's default `app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`. However, for the profile page I created a `views/users/show.html.erb` file and rerouted from devise's default on my `config/routes.rb` file like so: `get 'show/:id' => 'user#show'`.

I implemented the appropriate spec tests on my `user_pages_spec.rb` file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

    subject { page }

    describe "profile page" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before { visit user_path(user) }

        it { should have_content(user.name) }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
    end


end
```

My `users_controller.rb` file:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end
```

end

And my `show.html.erb` file:

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>
```

When I run the tests, I receive this error:

```
Failures:

  1) User pages profile page should have title "Example User"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(user.name) }
     expected #has_title?("Example User") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.69 seconds
8 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page should have title              "Example User"
```

I am new at Rails and this is my first tutorial. I can't for the life of me figure out the error even though the solution seems to be straightforward?

Comment: show the layout that is being used?  do is do something with the :title?

Comment: have you tried `<% content_for :title, @user.name %>`

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code to your user_pages_spec.rb file

```
subject { page }

describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user <---------------
      visit user_path(user)
    end  
    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
end
```